# How to get HTML of the whole page without scrolling?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, python-requests

```
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def get_photos(nick,how_many):
    url = f"https://www.picuki.com/profile/{nick}"
    content = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
    images = [f["src"] for f in soup.findAll('img',class_="post-image")]
    for index, image in enumerate(images, start=1):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(image, f"/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Instagram_images/image{index}.png")
        if index == how_many: break
if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_photos("Username",20)
```

So I have this code which downloads images in png format from instagram. But problem is that this page only loads 18 images without scrolling. So if I input 18-36 I need to scroll down page one more time, if 36-54 I need to scroll down 2 times and get it's HTML. How to do it with request and is it even possible with this module?

Comment: I don't know what your source page is, but it's probably doing some sort of infinite scroll, getting more data from the server via AJAX or the Fetch API.  In that case, you would have to execute JavaScript to fetch the additional data.  (Or, just figure out what the API is and call it directly.)

Comment: I am kinda new in scraping. But I guess it's with infinite scrolling src="/app/assets/js/infinite-scroll.pkgd.js" I found this one in inspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images are loaded with Ajax, but you can emulate the Ajax with `requests` module.

This script will print all image URLs found on user profile:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


username = 'itsdougthepug'
base_url = 'https://www.picuki.com/profile/{username}'


def get_image_urls(username):

    url = base_url.format(username=username)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

    while True:
        for f in soup.findAll('img',class_="post-image"):
            yield f['src']

        load_more_url = soup.select_one('.load-more-wrapper[data-next]')
        if not load_more_url:
            load_more_url = soup.select_one('.pagination-next-page-input[value]')
            if load_more_url:
                load_more_url = load_more_url['value']
        else:
            load_more_url = load_more_url['data-next']

        if not load_more_url:
            break

        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.picuki.com' + load_more_url).content, 'html.parser')


for img in get_image_urls(username):
    print(img)
```

Prints:

```
https://scontent-sin6-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/103328423_965950027183296_957866876806120724_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-sin6-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=sW8Ic2lI-4UAX_b7bkB&oh=dc42f3f625065b6fba524bd39fc29cb0&oe=5EE7819B
https://scontent-sin6-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/103183716_3364797436946158_1962633742202963007_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-sin6-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=OjegUcacb2kAX_BGNBA&oh=92a8035ffed07e724a77617c6ff73b73&oe=5F0F1F22
https://scontent-sin6-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/102951446_2650089068539996_1395066409287738000_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-sin6-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=1&_nc_ohc=zXDXxxtqYUkAX9_1jE3&oh=06e83257c7a2b1cfea593719a3af60d2&oe=5F0D3F32
https://scontent-sin6-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/103290695_2721943028038123_664290938707092396_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-sin6-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=107&_nc_ohc=cZKGnM3wjBwAX9wsGvR&oh=132218410341a0ffc2d7d78f38904a01&oe=5F104353
https://scontent-sin6-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/103207650_283928112789317_1081832932435688252_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-sin6-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=105&_nc_ohc=3XfsL50CwCoAX9k2_dN&oh=969bdf74e73466a39952957bfd8ec528&oe=5F0E2A91
https://scontent-sin6-2.cdninstagram.com/v/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/s640x640/102546510_111827600395599_8198630171951588410_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-sin6-2.cdninstagram.com&_nc_cat=103&_nc_ohc=cVJqLrxo-fUAX9fBZtG&oh=8edcc8a5bf56519d0155e6d23ac514b3&oe=5F0EA104

... and so on.
```